# How can i make the last twoitems align at bottom?

Tags: jquery, html, css, kendo-ui

I am using kendo controls and want to bottom-align both **split button** and **button** within the div, for some reason its not working out..how can i remove the gap on top?

I have tried margin-top and padding-top as 0.

```
<div class="row" style="padding-top:10px; margin-top:0px; margin-right:0px; padding-bottom:0px">
                <div class="col-md-8" style="padding-left:0px; border:dashed">
                    <label>Graphs per row:</label>
                    @Html.TextBox("txtGraphsPerRow", "4", new { @class = "k-textbox", @style = "width:25px" })
                </div>
                <div style="float:right; border:dashed;"  >
                    <ul id="myMenu">
                        <li onclick="" class="defaultItem" data-action="1">Print Graphs</li>
                        <li class="emptyItem">
                            <span class="empty">&nbsp;</span>
                            <ul>
                                <li>Print All Students in List</li>
                                <li>Include School Logo</li>
                                <li>Include School Photo</li>
                                <li>
                                    Page Orientation
                                    <ul>
                                        <li>Portrait</li>
                                        <li>Landscape</li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    Page Size
                                    <ul>
                                        <li>A4</li>
                                        <li>A3</li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <button id="btnCloseGraph">Close</button>
                </div>
            </div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give `vertical-align:top` to `myMenu` and `btnCloseGraph` id.